# Checking if command response does not contain str

Tags: bash, string-comparison

I have a script which works great... but I'd like it not do anything if there is no one online. I looked over all the documentation on how to check if a str is not within a variable, but it always thows the same error, which I assume may be something else, but literally nothing else is touched besides the addition of the fi at the bottom for the new if statement to check if there is no users online...

Error: `startAnnouncement.sh: 44: [[: not found`

```
#!/bin/bash

checkServer=$(/etc/init.d/minecraft status)
checkUsers=$(/etc/init.d/minecraft command list)
cd /.smc

# Is the server even running?
if [[ $checkServer =~ "is running" ]]; then

    #Is anyone online to even see the message...?
    if [[ ! $checkUsers =~ "are 0 out" ]]; then

       # No count file? Create it.
        if [ ! -f /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt ]; then
            echo 0 > /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt
        fi

        # Load count
        lastAnn=$(cat /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt)

        # ANNOUNCEMENTS
        announcement[0]='Dont  forget to check out http://fb.com/pyrexiacraftfans for news and updates'
        announcement[1]='Use our Facebook page to request land protection! Visit http://fb.com/pyrexiacraftfans'
        announcement[2]='Stay tuned for the announcement of our spawn build competition soon on our Facebook page!'
        announcement[3]='We have upgraded the server with mcMMO and Essentials Economy! Stay tuned for shop openings!'

        announcementText=${announcement[$lastAnn]}

        # Send announcement
        sendAnnouncement=$(/etc/init.d/minecraft command say $announcementText)

        # Next announcement count
        ((++lastAnn))

        # Write next announacment count
        # Should we restart announcement que?
        if [ $lastAnn -gt $((${#announcement[@]}-1)) ]; then
                echo 0 > /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt
        else
                echo $lastAnn > /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt
        fi

    fi

fi
```

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: Since you have `#!/bin/bash` in the script, do not run it like `sh myscript`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your conditions don't actually use regex-special chars,

```
if [[ $checkServer =~ "is running" ]]; then
    if [[ ! $checkUsers =~ "are 0 out" ]]; then
```

Also, you need to use `!~` operator on the 2nd condition: you have too many arguments

So you might as well use glob patterns.

```
if [[ $checkServer == *"is running"* ]]; then
    if [[ $checkUsers != *"are 0 out"* ]]; then
```

Comment: Same error `startAnnouncement.sh: 44: [[: not found` And the first if/else works just fine.

Comment: line 44 is the blank line before the last `fi`. Your error message does not correspond to the code you posted, so how can we help you?

Comment: I figured it out on my own, but for your information, the error code very much corresponded to your edits you had me make.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're running the script with a non-bash interpreter: `sh myscript` -- `[[` are a bash (and ksh, zsh) construct that a POSIX shell doesn't understand. Also, I bristle about "edits you had me make": I didn't make you do anything. You asked a bash question, I gave you a bash answer. Take it or leave it, but take responsibility for your actions.

Comment: No responsibility needed. You said the error doesn't come from your code. It does. It's as simple as that. I "took it" and didn't leave it, cause I am appreciative. I'm just letting you know as you seem to think that error has nothing to do with the code at hand, which it does. 

This is ran on CentOS through BASH. The header is clearly visible.

Comment: Please share your fixed code so that others with the same problem can gain from your efforts.

Comment: great for the double brackets hint